# PhpSpreadsheets VLOOKUP is not Format specific

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I have to edit a worksheet, which uses VLOOKUP.
In my template, VLOOKUP has to search for a value using an index, which is formatted like this:

[image]

When I now edit the template in PhpSpreadsheet and change a value or an index, which forces to recalculate VLOOKUP, PhpSpreadsheets CalculationEngine seems to ignore the specified format and delivers the wrong value(1 is 1 for PhpSpreadsheet, no matter the format). This is resolved, once you edit the spreadsheet again with Excel, however, I require the value of VLOOKUP **BEFORE** I can edit it again with Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I found out, that PhpSpreadsheets VLOOKUP function, wich can be found under PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/LookupRef.php, stringifies all values.
With the use of is_nummeric, which also returns true on stringified numbers, the function ignored datatypes.


Further explanation can be found under the issue I created:
[LookupRef function VLOOKUP is not datatype specific](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1402)


I corrected the bug in this Pull request:
[distinguish datatypes in VLOOKUP](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/pull/1403)